# How can I change the location of a projectile in pygame without changing its facing every loop?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have written the following code, it seems to me like it should work, but it appears "firedir" is constantly being set to "facing", not just on mouse click. With this code, when the character changes direction, or facing any projectile on the screen also changes direction. (This is in Python 3.3)

What is wrong with the way I wrote it?
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
def update(char1, laser_list, facing, firedir):
 keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
 if (keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]): 
    char1.rect.x -= 2
    facing = "left"
 elif (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]): 
    char1.rect.y += 2
    facing = "down"
 elif (keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]): 
    char1.rect.y -= 2
    facing = "up"
 elif (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]): 
    char1.rect.x += 2
    facing = "right"

 if laser_list:
    #Move the laser
    if firedir == "up":
        laser.rect.y -= 4
    elif firedir == "down":
        laser.rect.y += 4
    elif firedir == "left":
        laser.rect.x -= 4
    elif firedir == "right":
        laser.rect.x += 4


 return(facing)

#main loop
done = False
while not done:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if not laser_list:
            laser = Laser(facing)
            laser.rect.x = (char1.rect.x + 10)
            laser.rect.y = (char1.rect.y + 10)
            all_sprites_list.add(laser)
            laser_list.add(laser)

            firedir = facing


#update sprites
facing = update(char1, laser_list, facing, facing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that you're passing `facing` as `firedir`, when you should instead be reading the facing that you passed to the `Laser` constructor. I'm not sure where that is saved (since you don't show the `Laser` class definition), but I think you want to make `update` do something like:

```
def update(char1, laser_list): # fewer parameters
    # key reading stuff, as before, which sets the local variable `facing`

    for laser in laser_list:       # loop over all lasers in the list
        if laser.firedir == "up":  # check an attribute of the laser for its direction
            laser.rect.y -= 4
        elif laser.firedir == "down":
            laser.rect.y += 4
        elif laser.firedir == "left":
            laser.rect.x -= 4
        elif laser.firedir == "right":
            laser.rect.x += 4

    return facing  # the returned facing will be used for lasers fired in the next frame!
```

An alternative, which might be easier, is to store a `velocity` vector on the laser rather than a direction string. Then you can use the same update code regardless of what direction the laser is aimed (even diagonals, if you allow them, will just work). I don't know what the `Laser` setup code would be for that, but the `update` logic would be:

```
 laser.rect.x += laser.velocity.x
 laser.rect.y += laser.velocity.y
```